# How to run python websocket on gunicorn

Tags: python, flask

I found this 0 dependency python websocket server from SO: 
https://gist.github.com/jkp/3136208
I am using gunicorn for my `flask` app and I wanted to run this websocket server using `gunicorn` also.  In the last few lines of the code it runs the server with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(
        ("localhost", 9999), WebSocketsHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I cannot figure out how to get this `websocketserver.py` running in `gunicorn`.  This is because one would think you would want `gunicorn` to run `server_forever()` as well as the `SocketServer.TCPServer(...`.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUnicorn expects a WSGI application ([PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/)) not just a function. Your app has to accept an `environ` variable and a `start_response` callback and return an iterator of data (roughly speaking). All the machinery encapsuled by SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler is on gunicorn side. I imagine this is a lot of work to modify this gist to become a WSGI application (But that'll be fun!).

OR, maybe this library will get the job done for you: https://github.com/CMGS/gunicorn-websocket

Comment: This answers my question. It's already been written. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Flask-Sockets extension, you have a websocket implementation for gunicorn directly in the extension which make it possible to start with the following command line :

```
gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker app:app
```

Though I don't know if that's what you want to do.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I wound up using `tornado` instead. I found a sample app that got me started with most of I what I intended to implement. https://github.com/hiroakis/tornado-websocket-example/

Comment: Will write a tutorial soon on websockets with Python/Flask and JS. Because I struggled with it so I guess people could find it interesting.

Comment: Although I got Flask-Websockets initially working. I was unable to send out a message in response to an api call. For example in response to a `post` request.  In that example that is exactly what they do.

Comment: A websocket isn't meant to reponse to post requests. A Websocket will answer when it receives a message from the client without a Get/Post request. Because you have a direct connection between your client and your server. You have to set some JS code to use the WebSocket (at least that's how I understand it)

Comment: So if I want to use a websocket in the way that SO uses it... To update the user as soon as something happens.  Like a person accepts a friend request... That would be the server sending a message to the websocket server which would be picked up by the browser b/c it is listening. ?

Comment: Kind of. Update → Server sends a message via websocket → Client receives it and updates page. 
I don't really distinguish the server and the websocket server because it's in the same running server instance in my case.